# How to get digest representation of CryptoJS.HmacSHA256 in JS

Tags: javascript, python, cryptography, hmac, cryptojs

I have to generate string representation of `CryptoJS.HmacSHA256` in digest (bytes representation).

I need it because i have to duplicate python code  which generate such digest in javascript:

```
print hmac.new("secret", "test", hashlib.sha256).digest()

')�kb��>�y+������:�oΚ��H�   '
```

The goal is to duplicate behaviour of code above in javascript.

Could you please suggest me how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. What is the exact output format that you require? Just 32 bytes?

Comment: Beware that comparing HMAC values may result in a time based side channel attack, depending on the protocol used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need raw bytes then CryptoJS does not seem to supply code for it. It is mentioned that this is because of lack of cross browser compatibility for `Uint8Array` and friends.

However, after searching, I did find some conversion code created by    Vincenzo Ciancia:

```
CryptoJS.enc.u8array = {
    /**
     * Converts a word array to a Uint8Array.
     *
     * @param {WordArray} wordArray The word array.
     *
     * @return {Uint8Array} The Uint8Array.
     *
     * @static
     *
     * @example
     *
     *     var u8arr = CryptoJS.enc.u8array.stringify(wordArray);
     */
    stringify: function (wordArray) {
        // Shortcuts
        var words = wordArray.words;
        var sigBytes = wordArray.sigBytes;

        // Convert
        var u8 = new Uint8Array(sigBytes);
        for (var i = 0; i < sigBytes; i++) {
            var byte = (words[i >>> 2] >>> (24 - (i % 4) * 8)) & 0xff;
            u8[i]=byte;
        }

        return u8;
    },

    /**
     * Converts a Uint8Array to a word array.
     *
     * @param {string} u8Str The Uint8Array.
     *
     * @return {WordArray} The word array.
     *
     * @static
     *
     * @example
     *
     *     var wordArray = CryptoJS.enc.u8array.parse(u8arr);
     */
    parse: function (u8arr) {
        // Shortcut
        var len = u8arr.length;

        // Convert
        var words = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            words[i >>> 2] |= (u8arr[i] & 0xff) << (24 - (i % 4) * 8);
        }

        return CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(words, len);
    }
};
```

Note of course that bytes don't translate directly to characters; *you cannot use a text compare* to compare against `')�kb��>�y+������:�oΚ��H�   '` generated by python. For that you *do* need an encoder such as hexadecimals or base 64. In that case please look at the [answer from Artjom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29433000/589259) instead.

Comment: Note: I haven't tested the code above. There were a few people out there that seemed happy with it. I would recommend writing some tests around it though.

Comment: I haven't found the original source of the code, so I used a link to your post from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29449521). Can you provide one?

Answer (score 47):

You can't simply send bytes to JavaScript. You need to convert this to a textual representation for it to be comparable. Hex encoding is supported by both python's hmac module and CryptoJS.

CryptoJS:

```
CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("test", "secret").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
```

Python2:

```py
hmac.new("secret", "test", hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

Python3:

```py
hmac.new("secret".encode("utf-8"), "test".encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

Note the difference in the argument ordering.

All produce

```
0329a06b62cd16b33eb6792be8c60b158d89a2ee3a876fce9a881ebb488c0914
```

Comment: Fun fact, if you're using Shopify's liquid hmac_sha256 string filter, it also outputs the Hex value.

Comment: In the case of Python - you cannot pass String to `hmac.new()` method. If I pass string I am receiving this error: `TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'`

Comment: @SlickSlime Yes, this answer was written for Python 2. You would have to encode the (Unicode) string first