# What is the JavaScript/node.js function HMACSHA256()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I am trying to find information about this JavaScript/node.js function:

```
HMACSHA256()
```

Its mentioned e.g. here:

- https://jwt.io/introduction (scroll to section "Signature")
- https://hirosht.medium.com/customized-jwt-encoded-with-hmac-sha256-hs256-267574bd7639 (scroll to section "Signature;")

It's mentioned in other places too.

Neither node.js nor any browser JavaScript provides any function with that name.

So what is it? Is it pseudo code or is it a dummy function or simply a mistake everybody copies and pastes?

Comment: It appears to be (have been?) a function provided by the CryptoJS library, according to [How to get digest representation of CryptoJS.HmacSHA256 in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29432506/215552)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [standard algorithum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).

The JWT documentation is providing psuedo-code (and also links off to JWT specific libraries that you should probably be using instead of writing your own implementation).

The blog you've found has code examples using [Crypto-JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was confused because everything else e.g. in the blog article is concrete JS/node code.

Answer (score 1):

You need a plugin named "crypto"
It has "createHmac" function where you can give "sha256" as an argument.

https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatehmacalgorithm-key-options